# "Connection timed out (Connection timed out)" Error for SQLActivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline

I have a connection timed out error on my data pipeline job to run a simple sql script. The script is set up in my S3. The data pipeline itself is in the region of us-east-1. My database is in us-east-2. When I first ran the pipeline I got the error "waiting on runner" and it never ran. I figured I should change my EC2 to us-east-2 to be in the same region as the database the SQL script is running on. I no long got "waiting on runner" but now I continuously get the error "connection timed out".

What's weird is all the AWS forum questions and documents say this is what happens when you attempt to connect to a database from outside EC2  but since I'm using EC2 I have no idea what the issue could be. Any suggestions would be very helpful and I'm happy to provide more details as needed.

Getting this error now in my logs: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Answer (score 0):

Typical issues with connectivity arise out of the following:

1. Is your DB allowing incoming connection from you EC2.
2. In your DB Security Group what is the source for the DB port.
3. If the DB and the EC2 are in different VPC's, are the VPC's peered.

Comment: It appears that even though I specified the region for my EC2 in the "run on" parameter to be in us-east-2 it is still in us-east-1. Additionally it has a different VPC IDs. How do I peer them? They are still in different regions btw.

Comment: if you really do not have a need for 2 VPC, i would recommend putting everything into the Same VPC. VPC peering is a bit complex, started here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html

Comment: I remade the pipeline in the same region with the same security group giving it the same VPC as my data warehouse. Still something wrong and I still get the connection timed out error. Any suggestions? This couldn't be a firewall issue could it? They are both in the same region.

Comment: pls post details/screenshots of what you see in SG's for both the DB and the EC2 instance.